# Using multiple info.plist variations with a fallback in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, info.plist

I am using different info.plist files for various configurations (dev, release, etc).  It was easy to do in the project editor.  However, only a fraction of the properties vary amongst the different plist flavors.  So, I'd like to have a single fallback where I can put things like version, icons, etc.  I can't find a way to do this though.  I see various project settings for things like "Info.plist Preprocessor Definitions".  Maybe it can be done there.  Anyone know how this might be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easier if you keep a single plist file but pass in compile time flags for your different targets.

I have had great success with using Preprocessor Macros configured different for targets.

[Some info in the apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/115-Configuring_Applications/configuring_applications.html)

Comment: Shaun, thanks for the answer.  I'm not sure what you mean by "pass in compile time flags".  Are you talking about using #if directives and whatnot?

Comment: Hey Steve, you could use the #if directives or say for example you have a preprocessor macro such as `SERVICE='@"http://www.example.com"'` set then in your code anywhere for a test you should be able to go `NSLog(SERVICE)` and it should print out `"http://www.example.com"`

Comment: This way you can pass in at build time different values for your macros so Debug, Release may have different values for SERVICE.  This way your plist is the same but just the environment props will be different.

Comment: Thanks Shaun, I was able to figure it out and kept the single plist file.  Thanks again for such a helpful answer!

Answer (score 0):

In your target, in the Info.plist File section (Xcode 8) you can set a path for your file for each build configuration.